# getting Incorrect syntax near '08'. error

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have been doing some research about how to pass variables to an openquery. Here is the query I have built.

```
DECLARE @firstday int;
DECLARE @lastday int;

SELECT @firstday = CONVERT(nvarchar(8), (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)), 112)
SELECT @lastday = CONVERT(nvarchar(8), (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)), 112)

DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(EPAK,
''SELECT WOADAT,WOROUT,BCDESC,WDWO#,BCSIZE,BCCHG
FROM CUST INNER JOIN (BCDE INNER JOIN (WO2 INNER JOIN WO1
ON (WDCMP = WOCMP) AND (WDCUS# = WOCUS#) AND (WDWO# = WOWO#)) ON (BCCMPY = WDCMP) 
AND (BCSIZE = WDSIZE) AND (BCCHG = WDCHG)) ON (CCMPNY = BCCMPY) AND (CCUST# = WDCUS#)
WHERE (((WOADAT) between @firstday and @lastday) AND ((WDCMP)=''08''))order by WDWO#'')'

EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SqlCommand;
```

My linked server is a DB2 server and when I run my query I am getting the following error

```
Incorrect syntax near '08'.
```

When I double clic on it, it highlighted this

```
SELECT @lastday = CONVERT(nvarchar(8), (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)), 112)
```

Could someone please take a look and let me know what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need two more single quotes:

```
((WDCMP)=''''08''''))
```

You have a quoted string being passed in as a query.  Two levels of quoting.  I think the problem is happening after the first round of substitution, which produces:

```
((WDCMP)='08'))
```

This "looks" right, but not for a quoted substring.  The first quote ends the substring, generating the error.

Comment: Beat me by 12 seconds.. :)

Comment: Or parameterize it - declare the inner command as a parameter and pass it to `sp_execsql`. This way you don't have to deal with more than one level of nested quotes

Comment: when I add those quotes and run the query I got this error OLE DB provider "IBMDA400" for linked server "EPAK" returned message "SQL0206: Column or global variable FIRSTDAY not found.
Cause . . . . . :   FIRSTDAY was not found as a column of table *N in *N and was not found as a global variable in *N. If the table is *N, FIRSTDAY is not a column of any table or view that can be referenced.

Comment: Lc, how can I do that? could you please write the statement?

Comment: @cojimarmiami . . . I did.  You need four single quotes before and after the `08`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please see my previous comment

Comment: @cojimarmiami . . . That is an entirely different problem.  You need to actually put the values into the string or use `sp_executesql`.  Variables are not inherited when you execute dynamic SQL.